# Add / Remove row(s) in ag-grid

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

How to add or remove a row in ag-grid,
i try this, but not work

```
$scope.gridOptions.rowData.push(data);
```

and with this

```
scope.gridOptions.api.forEachNode( function(node) {
    var data = node.data;
    updatedNodes.push(vehicle);
});

$scope.gridOptions.api.refreshRows(updatedNodes);
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to call the api.setRowData(rowData) every time you need to add or remove row.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The current version of ag-grid now supports this:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-insert-remove/

The grid does feature change detection but if you want/need to force a refresh, you can pick one of the refresh methods:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-refresh/

Comment: yes supported.. But this is not based on angularjs1

Comment: This is all very nice, but I still don't understand how I make the grid refresh and show the update data from the object inside the Angular code (thus, *adding* a new row, not editing an existing one). For example, I have an object named "gridData" that holds the initial set of records for the grid. It shows up nicely in the grid on load. Now, I'm *adding* an item to the array in this object (inside my angular script file, .ts) and I need the table on the screen to show that...

Comment: You can pick one of the refresh api functions:https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-refresh/

Comment: @AlexanderZbinden your link provides info about `refresh`, but @TheCuBeMan asked about  `insert`. Here is a correct info about `insert` (`updateRowData` +  `add`): https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/ and exactly worked part `this.gridApi.updateRowData({add:[your data here], addIndex:0});`

Answer (score 16):

This is what worked for me with the ag-grid community version 22.1.1:

add new row

```
const row = //someNewRowDataHere

this.gridOptions.rowData.push(row)
this.gridApi.setRowData(this.gridOptions.rowData)
```

remove

```
const selectedRow = this.gridApi.getFocusedCell()
const id = this.gridOptions.rowData[selectedRow.rowIndex].i

this.gridOptions.rowData.splice(selectedRow.rowIndex, 1)
this.gridApi.setRowData(this.gridOptions.rowData)
```

Comment: Needed to delete rows and this works great, glad I don't need to pull the data from server for a simple delete.

Comment: @eddy My idea here was answering how to delete or add without having to pull all the rows from the server again. If your question is about the add and delete calls to the server something like this should work(using axios):


axios.post('some route', row)


axios.delete('some route', id)

Comment: No, my intention is also only update a certain row after the typical CRUD operations. For example after an insert or delete. I don't want to pull all the records again. My only concern is that, if I'm not mistaken, rowData is only used for the client-side model and I'm the server-side row model

Comment: @eddy Yes, my answer is client side, i haven't tried it server side. If this also works server side mind writing it later? Else make your own answer I would like to see it.

Answer (score 7):

I personally like this approach

**Add row**

```
$( '#newRow' ).on( 'click', function() {
    gridOptions.api.applyTransaction({ add: gridOptions.rowData });
} );
```

**Remove row (ex. clicking on a bin-icon)**

Works with `rowDragManaged` enabled

```
// remove row
$( document ).on( 'click', '#myGridFees .fa-trash-alt', function(e) {
    $.fn.agGridRemoveRowByBinClick(gridFeeOptions, $(this));
});


/**
 *
 * @param agGridOption
 * @param $this
 */
$.fn.agGridRemoveRowByBinClick = function(agGridOption, $this) {
    let id = $this.closest('.ag-row').attr( 'row-id' );
    agGridOption.api.applyTransaction({ remove: [ agGridOption.api.getRowNode(id).data ] });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since this answer is a bit old, just noting another update to the grid has emphasized the use of what the grid calls "transactions" for all grid CRUD operations:

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/#gsc.tab=0